# MySQL sum rows by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have db with orders i need sum price by date range

| id | company | item | date_start | date_end | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | B | item1 | 2021-12-01 | 2021-12-10 | 5 |
| 2 | B | item2 | 2021-12-20 | 2021-12-25 | 10 |

```
SELECT company, SUM(price) AS company_sum FROM `orders` GROUP BY company
```

Price 1 day of item1 = 5

Price 1 day of item2 = 10

I need sum with days

Comment: show a table containing the exact result you would want from the query, please.

Comment: I didn't understand what you want. Please give more information

Comment: Example of my table I added in the question

Comment: I need sum final price, 1 day booking item1 = 5
date_start = 2021-12-01
date_end = 2021-12-10
So, have 10 days, 10 * 5 = 50

Answer (score 5):

> I need sum final price, 1 day booking item1 = 5 date_start = 2021-12-01 date_end = 2021-12-10 So, have 10 days, 10 * 5 = 50 – Elexer

```
SELECT company, 
       SUM(price * (1 + DATEDIFF(date_end, date_start))) AS company_sum 
FROM `orders` 
GROUP BY company
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```sql
SELECT company, SUM(price) AS company_sum 
FROM `orders` 
WHERE DATE >= '2021-12-01' AND DATE < '2021-12-20'
GROUP BY company
```

Comment: Return result: NULL